# How to inject own services in Controller

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I tried to inject my own service in my api controller, but it throws an **InvalidOperationException**. It is unable to resolve the service. (.NET 5)

What I am doing wrong?

```
public class MyController : ControllerBase
{
    private readonly MyService _myService;

    public ContractsController(MyService service)
    {
        myService = service;
    }


    [HttpGet("{id}")]
    public Item GetItemById(string id)
    {
        return _myService.getContract(id);
    }
}
```

This is my Startup file:

```
public class Startup
    {
        public Startup(IConfiguration configuration)
        {
            Configuration = configuration;
        }

        public IConfiguration Configuration { get; }

        // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to add services to the container.
        public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {

            services.AddControllers();
            services.AddSwaggerGen(c =>
            {
                c.CustomOperationIds(selector => $"{selector.HttpMethod.ToLower().Pascalize()}{selector.ActionDescriptor.RouteValues["controller"]}");
                c.SwaggerDoc("v1", new OpenApiInfo { Title = "My.Portal.Server", Version = "v1" });
            });
            services.AddCors(options =>
            {
                options.AddDefaultPolicy(builder =>
                {
                    builder.SetIsOriginAllowed(origin => new Uri(origin).IsLoopback)
                    .WithOrigins(Configuration.GetSection("AllowedOrigins").Get<string[]>())
                    .AllowAnyHeader()
                    .AllowAnyMethod();
                });
            });
        }

        // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to configure the HTTP request pipeline.
        public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
        {
            if (env.IsDevelopment())
            {
                app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
                app.UseSwagger();
                app.UseSwaggerUI(c => c.SwaggerEndpoint("/swagger/v1/swagger.json", "My.Portal.Server v1"));
            }

            app.UseHttpsRedirection();

            app.UseRouting();

            app.UseAuthorization();

            app.UseCors();

            app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
            {
                endpoints.MapControllers();
            });
        }
    }
```

If i create a new instance in the constructor, then it is working.

thank you in advance!

Comment: .NET Core/5.0, or .NET 4.7 or earlier?

Comment: You need to bootstrap the DI. The way you do that is different in Core and 5.0 to .NET 4.7 and earlier.

Comment: i am using .NET 5.0

Comment: can you please show me an example

Comment: Can you post the contents of your ConfigureServices method from Startup.cs file please? Maybe you missed registering your service in ServiceCollection.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Example, as per request in comment:

```
        public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {
             services.AddScoped<IInfoStorageService>(c => new InfoStorageService(Configuration["ImageInfoConnectionString"]));
```

This is telling the application to pass an instance of InfoStorageService in where IInfoStorageService is injected. It is instantiated with a connection string that it reads from configuration.

`AddScoped` means that the injected service will be the same across the request. You can also use `AddTransient()` which means it will not match any other uses of the service, or you can use `AddSingleton()`, which means it will use the same instance through the whole lifetime of the application.